# Mat-tab expand out of his parent when flexbox direction is row

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I would like to divide the window into two columns, one will have a `mat-tab-group`, and the other one things.

To achieve this I want to use flexbox, but, when I set the parent `display` as `flex`, and the children's `flex` as 2 and 1, if there is a `mat-tab-group`, the child with the tab group expand totally to show all the tabs.

[Here a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xa7gbq) to have a better representation.

On the stackblitz, there is two test, the first one with the mat group, and the issue. The second one, without mat group but with what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is feasible for you to provide a `max-width` rule to your `mat-tab-group` parent container, that could help you work around this issue.

```
.div1 {
  flex: 2;
  background-color: blue;
  max-width: 66.66%;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d6yurf?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html

Comment: Well, it seams more like a hack but for now it works so thanks :), if I don't find anything else or if nobody can help me more, I will give you the answer.

Comment: Sure thing, and I agree, it feels a bit hacky. Playing with these Material Components I've notice many expect to be used a certain way so they can be a bit touchy.

Comment: Didn't found anything else, but in this case I will personally don't use flex because it's useless if I set the width in percentage, just use inline-block.